# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ARTapToPlaceObject.UpdatePlacementPose

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my logs:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ARTapToPlaceObject.UpdatePlacementPose () (at Assets/Resources/Scripts/ARTapToPlaceObject.cs:54)
ARTapToPlaceObject.Update () (at Assets/Resources/Scripts/ARTapToPlaceObject.cs:32)
```

[image]
My code:

```
private void UpdatePlacementPose()
{
    var screenCenter = Camera.current.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));
    var hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
    aRRaycastManager.Raycast(screenCenter, hits, TrackableType.Planes);

    placementPoseIsValid = hits.Count > 0;
    if (placementPoseIsValid)
    {
        PlacementPose = hits[0].pose;
    }
}
```

I have a problem when I run my app ar camera is black screen, I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Camera.current
It might be blank. Try assigning the camera reference manually.

`private Camera arCamera;
var screenCenter = arCamera.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));`